# Can I return a generic type inside of a ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, generics, valuetuple

Here's some code for an example. I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'T'"

```
public ValueTuple<string, T> TestMethod<T>()
{
    return ("test", "");
}
```

How would I go about doing this? Is this outside of the limitations of ValueTuple?

Example of real code I am using

```
public ValueTuple<bool, T> RunSelectAllCommand<T>(MySqlCommand command, 
    List<MySqlParameter> parameterCollection) where T : class
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();            
        cmd.CommandText = command.CommandText;

        // if parameters for query are specified, add them here.
        if (parameterCollection != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameterCollection.ToArray());
        }
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // We're selecting all keys from registration database 
            // this is probably a horrible design. oh, well...
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(KeyRow))
            {
                List<KeyRow> data = new List<KeyRow>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new KeyRow(reader["keycode"].ToString(), 
                        reader["apikey"].ToString(), 
                        reader["ipaddress"].ToString(),
                        DateTime.Parse(reader["date"].ToString()), 
                        reader["hwid"].ToString() ?? ""));
                }

                return (true, data as T);
            }
        }
    }

    return (false, null);
}
```

Comment: This isn't exclusive to ValueTuple. You'd get the same behavior with `public T TestMethod<T>() => string.Empty;` Why does this method need to be generic? It clearly intends to return a `ValueTuple<string,string>`

Comment: @JonathonChase I wrote a MySql wrapper method that will return a list of objects depending on the object type specified when the method is called, and I'm refactoring it to use ValueTuple. The above method is just an example showing the behavior.

Comment: How do you expect there to be a conversion from `string` to `T` that is applied automatically?

Comment: Could you make it return type (string, object)? Or make a tuple factory that returns the right kind of tuple based on an enum you pass it?

Comment: @DannyNeumann return type (string, object) works. That makes more sense anyways. Thank you.

Comment: `public ValueTuple<string, T> TestMethod<T>() => (string.Empty, default(T));` has no issue compiling. The issue you have is trying to use a string in place of T, when T is not guaranteed to be a string.

Comment: return ("test", default(T)); would compile and run fine

Comment: @JonathonChase I understand where I was confused. Changing the return type to (string, object) achieves what I needed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using `object` generally means your code has a bigger problem. If you can constrain `T` to `class`, you can do `public (string, T) Test<T>() where T : class => ("test", "" as T);`.

Comment: @NetMage Can you expand upon how using `object` is generally problematic? Curious to learn about that.

Comment: what about `return ("test", default(T));`? Your example is poor because you're returning a different type than you've stated you'll return in the signature, but you haven't described to us why you're doing that.

Comment: @TomFarley returning `object` is generally problematic because the caller now has to do some kind of validation/conversion to get it to the type they expect. You should probably return some object of type `T` instead of `object`. But the way you're using generics in your example doesn't make sense, since you aren't taking in any parameters of type `T`, nor producing any. An actual example would probably get you a better answer.

Comment: @RufusL I updated the question with an actual example of code I am using in my project. It reflects the suggestion by NetMage as well and seems to be working fine, but I am obviously open to any criticism or suggestions.

Comment: @TomFarley Your example may as well just be a non-generic function that returns type of `ValueTuple<bool, List<KeyRow>>` and remove the type check, as it only ever returns `(bool, List<KeyRow>)` or `(bool, null as T)`. You could also consider adding a `Func<IDataReader, T>` delegate that handles mapping from a reader row to your T, the add the result of calling it to your List<T> response.

Comment: @TomFarley I'm also somewhat suspicious that your current implementation will only return `(true, null)` or `(false, null)` since data is a `List<KeyRow>` and you're trying to cast it to `KeyRow`

Comment: @JonathonChase It is a generic function because in the future I will not always use `KeyRow` - the method is untested but you're probably right about it returning null because of casting `List<KeyRow>` to `KeyRow`.

Comment: `return (false, null);` is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, I whipped out the following as an example of how to do what you're trying to do. This uses a generic implementation method for reuse over the various types you might be returning, an a non-generic method to expose returning those types.

```
public ValueTuple<bool, List<KeyRow>> RunSelectAllKeyRowCommand(IDbCommand command, List<IDataParameter> parameterCollection) =>
    RunSelectAllCommandImpl<KeyRow>(command, 
                                    parameterCollection,
                                    reader => new KeyRow(reader["keycode"].ToString(), reader["apikey"].ToString(), reader["ipaddress"].ToString(), DateTime.Parse(reader["date"].ToString()), reader["hwid"].ToString() ?? ""));

private ValueTuple<bool, List<T>> RunSelectAllCommandImpl<T>(IDbCommand command, List<IDataParameter> parameterCollection, Func<IDataReader, T> mapper) where T : class
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = GetDataConnection())
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = command.CommandText;

        foreach(var parameter in parameterCollection) // if parameters for query are specified, add them here.
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<T> data = new List<T>();

            while (reader.Read())
                data.Add(mapper(reader));

            return (true, data);
        }
    }

    return (false, null);
}
```

Comment: This is very informative and has introduced a few new concepts to me so thank you.

Comment: `return (false, null);` is never reached.

Comment: C# tuple syntax can be used instead of the .NET Types and meaningful names can be given to the tuple values: `(bool _, List<T> data)`.